# JavaFX webengine override network

Tags: java, network-programming, javafx

I have been trying to figure out how to override the fx webengine to utilize a custom network interface that is not active on the OS but handled within the application.

For instance, the java.net classes will not be utilized, but a separate, custom network class, will be utilized to encapsulate the HTTP payload.

Trying to avoid the option of building my own browser when the fx webview already suites my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to implement your own protocol handler (or supplant the default http handler in the jdk), using the techniques outlined in: [A New Era for Java Protocol Handlers](http://media.techtarget.com/tss/static/articles/content/dm_protocolHandlers/java_protocol.pdf).

The key method is [URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory%28java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory%29).

Comment: Cool, looks like this work work then. So I could implement my URLStreamHandlerFactory to handle HTTP connections. And in that it would have my own protocol handler that would extend the sun.net.www.protocol.http class to override the read and write methods?